# int lambda expressions with string/octals? (C++)

Tags: c++, string, octal

I've been given an open book test, and been told I can use any resources I need to be able to answer the questions as it's more of an aptitude test - and one question has me really stumped.

The question asks to write a similar function to the given - which I'm sure I can do - but I can't find much information about what the function is doing, and given a small sample it's tricky to determine what is happening.

The question is as follows:

**What does the program print? Please write an equivalent getValue function.**

```
int t[]={1,2,3};
int getValue(int i)
{
  return "\5\3\8"[t[i]];    
}
void main()
{
  printf("%d",getValue(2));    
}
```

The program prints '0', which is the easy part. And I am tempted to answer with a simple method that returns just that. But I want a deeper understanding of what exactly is going on in the getValue function. My main curiosity is what the string part does in terms of the lambda expression, as \8 isn't a valid octal but seems to have some effect on the resulting values.

Not looking for a straight out answer (from what I gather that's why I use the homework tag), just a push in the right direction

Thanks for the help

Comment: This program contains no lambda expressions.

Comment: "\8" is undefined behavior in C++03, implementation defined in C++11, undefined behavior in C90, and requires a diagnostic in C99. So the answer to the question depends on which standard and/or implementation you're looking at.

Comment: Ahh - thought it was using them, late night cramming and searching with over thinking failed me. Thanks all!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The escape codes are not octal, I believe they are decimal. In any case, they are irrelevant as long as they occupy only a single byte.

Tracing the execution of this is trivial. First, we consider a substitution for the parameter

```
int t[]={1,2,3};
int getValue()
{
  return "\5\3\8"[t[2]];    
}
int main() //int, not void
{
  printf("%d",getValue());    
}
```

The third value of `t` is 3, which yields the *fourth* character in the string. As the string literal is three characters, plus NULL terminator, then the fourth character is the NULL terminator. When converted to an integer, this value is zero. The `printf` call prints this integer correctly. A similar function would simply index into the string directly, for example.

Comment: The first two escape codes are octal.  The `\8` has implementation-defined semantics because `8` is not an octal digit and is not one of the other well-defined escape sequences.

Comment: I feel silly now - over thought this one way too much. Thanks heaps for the help - unfortunately I cannot upvote until I get more rep :(

Answer (score 2):

Well, trace the execution. First, getValue is called with 2. Inside, it first calculates the value of t[i], which is t[2], which is 3. Then, it takes the character at index 3 from the string.

This part deserves a bit of explaining. The string constant consists of 4 characters - ASCII 5, ASCII 3, ASCII 8, and the terminating null (ASCII 0). Since string indexing is zero-based in C, the character at index 3 is null. It's retrieved from the string, extended from char to int (as the function returns an int), and returned. There, it's prompty printed.

The `\__` notation in strings means "Character with code __".

Comment: Thanks for the answer Seva - I feel rather silly for over thinking the question now

Answer (score 0):

Check out C FAQ 6.11.  Steve Summit requests that folks do not post direct URLs to the FAQ item, so start from http://www.c-faq.com/ and navigate to 6.11.

Also note Michael Burr's comment-response to OP.